# Can't install 23.10 - the whole VM will just freeze

Tags: 23.10

I have tried it 5 times and it still cannot install 23.10. I am running the latest VirtualBox 7.0.12, and during the installation process, the whole VM seems to freeze.

The time inside the VM at the top says: 10:09 (the current time in the morning), and then for a few or even 20 minutes, it stays as 10:09.

Anybody know how to make it work?  My machine is a ASUS ROG laptop.

**Update:** I just downloaded 22.04 LTS, and it installed in one shot.

Comment: Are you allocating enough memory. I’ve found that I need a bit more than 4GB.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right "Type" and "Version" for the newly created Virtual Machine? You should also give some (memory and disk size) information about the host machine.

Comment: please see the update in the question: I just downloaded 22.04 LTS, and it installed in one shot. My machine, I will need to check, but I think it is 16GB, and I think I allocated 8GB for the VM. But even if it is 4GB, shouldn't it say: "installation unsuccessful. Out of memory. Please increase your RAM." By the way, I thought Linux is famous for being able to be installed with very little RAM (even 1GB or 512MB)

Comment: ok, I checked. The laptop is 16GB, but I used the default 2GB RAM suggested by VirtualBox. So I tried a new one with 8GB RAM, and it installed. So I will put it as the answer. It is strange though why it'd freeze

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I was using 2GB RAM as VirtualBox suggested. After changing it to 8GB, it worked. (my computer has 16GB RAM).

@mpboden suggested even 4GB may be too little in the comment under the original question.

Comment: Minimum requirements for Desktop specify 4 GB RAM: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop . A non-GUI Ubuntu (Server) installation can run happily with 1 GB though.

Comment: ok, either VirtualBox is not doing the job (could have defaulted to 4GB when it detected Ubuntu GUI 2023.10 or even give a warning), or that Ubuntu could have flagged an error or warning: minimum 4GB RAM is required. Well, maybe the people working on them are like my coworkers: not know what's going on. Do something and report it done and managers don't care. What they often say is, "WTF", "it is what it is", or "if it doesn't work, it doesn't work."